# Chrome Extension: Alarms not being fired

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that uses the chrome alarms api. The alarms are not being triggered consistently. They get triggered most of the times and it works fine. However, sometimes they don't get triggered at all, even though they have been created.

I can see that the alarms have been created on the console, and that it's past the scheduledTime.

Also, if one of the alarms does not get triggered, then the remaining alarms don't get triggered either. If I restart chrome, then those alarms fire right away when it reopens.

What might be causing this inconsistent behavior? And how can I ensure that the alarms get triggered every time?

```js
chrome.alarms.getAll((alarm) => console.log(alarm))
```

[Alarms exist. The first alarm is 20 min past the scheduled time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleas.png)

Comment: alarm API is not a swiss clock; anyway I noticed that playing with the PC clock (going back and forth) sends alarms in tilt.
Of course I don't know if this can be your case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Running chrome.alarms.getAll shows the alarm and the correct scheduled time.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem in 2024. The alarms are set right; they just don't go off. My windows machine is not having the problem, but my Mac is. When I clear all the data, it's fine for a while on the Mac. Really frustrating.